# CMake_Error, gazebo_ros

Tags: gazebo, catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, when i try to use catkin_make for my workspace, i got this error

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo_ros" with
  any of the following names:

    gazebo_rosConfig.cmake
    gazebo_ros-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gazebo_ros" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gazebo_ros_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "gazebo_ros" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mohamed/Documents/workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mohamed/Documents/workspace/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:1914: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

my workspace contain only this package in the src: https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Kinematics-Project

i removed my gazebo and installed a new version gazebo9, i thought this what cause the error so i removed it and installed gazebo7 again.

when i try to use catkin_make with a workspace which doesn't contain any thing related to gazebo it works fine.
i am using Ubuntu 16, gazebo 7.14.0, kinetic-kame.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305359/cmake_error,-gazebo_ros/) by [mohamed ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/37345/mohamed-ahmed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-10-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `gazebo_ros` package doesn't seem to be installed, check if `rospack find gazebo_ros` return a path and if not install the package : `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros`.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohamed ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/37345/mohamed-ahmed/) on 2018-10-10**:
thank you my friend, it works like magic

**Comment by [Abdel_Meguid](https://answers.ros.org/users/73656/abdel_meguid/) on 2021-05-23**:
Thank you for your solution ...i wish for you a happy day